# Next.js Amplify Serverless AppSync graphql (Amplify error)

Tags: next.js, aws-appsync, amplifyjs

I'm trying to create an App that uses Amplify and AppSync with Next.js.

I was able to deploy the application successfully but when I'm trying to access the application (trying to fetch data from AppSync) It is failing.

I'm kinda lost what needs to be looked at, the application seems to be working fine locally but when I'm publishing it on AWS it is failing.

I'm getting error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getName' of undefined
//quotes.js

```
import { Connect } from 'aws-amplify-react';
........
<Connect
query={graphqlOperation(queries.getName)}
subscription={graphqlOperation(subscriptions.onCreateName)}
onSubscriptionMsg={(prev, { onCreateName }) => ({
...prev,
getName: {
...prev.getName,
items: [
...prev.getName.items,
onCreateName,
],
},
})}
```

>

Has anybody come across such an issue or any idea to resolve the issue?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Running the subscription when doing SSR is not needed / useful and requires a WebSocket client in the server, you can try [Dynamic Imports with no SSR](https://nextjs.org/docs/#with-no-ssr) to have the subscription only happen on the client. (using `{ ssr: false }`)

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

const DynamicComponentWithNoSSR = dynamic(() => import('../components/hello3'), { ssr: false });

function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <DynamicComponentWithNoSSR />
      <p>HOME PAGE is here!</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```